# Android create mosaic in row item adapter recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to create item adapter with a mosaic view include multiple images.
I found some libs: [AndroidMosaicLayout](https://github.com/adhamenaya/AndroidMosaicLayout), 
[QuiltViewLibrary](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary).

But these show on the main view. In my case, I want to show images on the item adapter `recyclerview`.
It's same the row on facebook row new feed.
[image: View Image]

Any help, thanks.

Comment: `QuiltView` is just a `FrameLayout`, so you should be able to put it in a `RecyclerView` item with no problem. `AndroidMosaicLayout` is a `NestedScrollView`, so you could put it in `RecyclerView` items, as well, but it's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cam do it using the library `AndroidMosaicLayout`. In the layout used for the adapter of the `RecyclerView` just add the view of AndroidMosiacLayout and inside the recyclerview adapter, just inflate the layout resources and access the AndroidMosiacLayout normally by assigning the required layout pattern and data. At the end the AndroidMosiacLayout it is just a NestedScrollView, so you can use it the same way you use any other view or view group.